# How to import file variables in JS file of Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have made a separate file for routes.

Here is the structure:

I have a separate folder for every module.

```
->routes->admin->userRoutes.js,contactRoutes.js etc
```

Then, inside `routes->admin.js` I import those files like this:

```
import contactsRoutes from './admin/customerRoutes'
import userRoutes from './admin/userRoutes'
```

Again, in `router.js`, I want to include `admin.js` so I can use both  `contactsRoutes` and `userRoutes` inside `router.js`:

```
import './routes/admin.js'
```

Here is our customerRoutes.js this file contacines routes of this module. i means all the routes of customer CRUD
`customerRoutes.js`

````
import CustomerList from '@/views/apps/customers/CustomersList.vue';
export default
    [{
        path: '/customers',
        name: 'customers',
        component: CustomerList,
        title: 'People',
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', active: true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/customers/view/:id',
        name: 'customers-view',
        component: () =>
            import('@/views/apps/customers/CustomerView.vue'),
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'View', active: true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    }
        ,
    {
        path: '/customers',
        name: 'customers',
        component: () =>
            import('@/views/apps/customers/CustomersList.vue'),
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', active: true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    }, {
        path: '/customers/view/:id',
        name: 'customers-view',
        component: () =>
            import ('@/views/apps/customers/CustomerView.vue'),
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'View', active:true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/customers/add',
        name: 'customers-add',
        component: () =>
            import ('@/views/apps/customers/CustomerAdd.vue'),
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'Add', active : true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/customers/edit/:id',
        name: 'customers-edit',
        component: () =>
            import ('@/views/apps/customers/CustomerEdit.vue'),
        meta: {
            breadcrumb: [
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'All Customers', url: '/customers' },
                { title: 'Edit', active : true },

            ],
            pageTitle: 'Customers',
            rule: 'admin',
            authRequired: true
        }
    },];
 ```

But, it is giving me an error that both variables are not available.

Is there any solution available?
````

Comment: Show us the content of your `./admin/customerRoutes` file :)

Comment: you have to export from `admin.js`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone is there any way to export all the variable from one file at a time?

Comment: `export default {contactsRoutes,userRoutes}`

Comment: then again i have to import in ```router.js```?

Comment: I am importing like this ```import * as adminRoutes from './routes/admin.js'```

But it is object now and I can not iterate it in my router.js